# Results returned from Prestashop do not match given values in plist...expected behaviour?

Tags: ios, plist, prestashop, appixia

I have created a mobile app using appixia for an existing site...our existing site has existing users, who have put their existing addresses into our database (prestashop/mysql).

One of these fields (Address Line 2) has been used for the UK County (similar to US States). As this was free text entry, users have used abbreviations etc in this field.

My mobile app I have generated, I want to use a plist for the users to select their county. This would work well for new users.

For existing users logging in, when prestashop returns their "county", and it DOESNT match a given value in the plist, what is the expected behaviour? This is difficult for me to simulate, but I would expect it to leave the field blank if no value sent from prestashop matches a plist value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to make sure I understood correctly, you are building your plist according to [this example](http://kb.appixia.com/modules%3aver1%3abasicformview), and in the `Value` fields you don't use a numerical value (like the example) but instead put the text of the county name. Since the Prestashop Address Line 2 is free-text, this works out and fills-in the name that you put in the `Value`.

If there isn't a full match to the user's current address, the expected behavior is either to leave this field empty or use the first selection value from the list. Not sure which is it, I suggest you test it out :) It's shouldn't be that hard to simulate, create a user in Prestashop through the website or the website backoffice and set a random value to Address Line 2. Then login using this user in the app. Another idea is to create a user in the app, and then using the website backoffice edit his address and change Address Line 2 to some random value, and then login once again through the app.

In any case, between login and re-login, it's best to restart your app (or the Visualizer), to make sure cookies are deleted and you're logged out.